# How to write unit test for controller in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing

I am new to laravel and want to unit test my controller in laravel 5.6
Here is my controller.

```
class NewOrdersController extends Controller
{
    protected $newOrders;

    public function __construct(NewOrderRepositoryInterface $newOrders)
    {
        $this->newOrders = $newOrders;
    }

   public function orderList(){
         $orders = $this->newOrders->getNewOrders();
         if(count($orders) == 0){
                return 0;
         }
         else{
                return 1;
         }
   }
}
```

My test looks like this. How can I write unit test for controller?

```
class NewOrderTest extends TestCase
{
    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function testMock(){
        $neworders = Mockery::mock('NewOrderRepositoryInterface');
        $neworders->shouldReceive('getNewOrders')
                        ->once()
                        ->andReturn(0);

        $orders = new newOrder($this->neworders);
        $this->assertEquals(0,$orders->orderList());
    }
}
```

Comment: When using Mockery it can be a good idea to add Men de use the Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryPHPUnitIntegration trait, this will turn your expectations in to assertions and call Mockery::close() for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mock is to replace the one you are already using, you should never Assert or test a mock. Instead usually you just make `mockX()` method, that binds the mock to the classes you want to replace. Also you have a funny binding on the interface, just use the class path as the binding, easier and you can derive it from `::class`. The mock will then automatically be loaded in the class, when you set it as the instance.

```
public function mockOrderRepository(){
    $neworders = Mockery::mock(NewOrderRepositoryInterface::class);
    $neworders->shouldReceive('getNewOrders')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(0);

    // bind the mocked class to the dependency injected version.
    $this->app->instance(NewOrderRepositoryInterface::class, $neworders);
}
```

I presumed it was a JsonApi, usually it is :) else mock your repository and call the endpoint and you can assert the data with `assertJson`

```
/** @test */
public function testOrderList()
{
    $this->mockOrderRepository;

    $response = $this->json('GET', 'v1/your/api/endpoint');

    $response->assertStatus(200);

    $response->assertJson(1);
}
```